# Casino - Luck with random - Python

Tags: python, random

Sorry for my English. Each month I go and play in casino, one time a month. My decision criteria: With random module find day and week to play in casino, only one exception, do not accept from random module the last month played week and day. For example, if I went 14th of October the day for November should be any day but not 14th. Here is my code: If I enter the same number “2” for example, the program doesn’t eliminate the number “2” my last month week. Please help.

```
import random

zz = raw_input ("Please enter the last week number: ")

fx = int(zz)

print fx



week_randoms=[]

gg = week_randoms


for i in range (4):

    gg = week_randoms

    gg.append(random.randrange(1,5))

print gg

hh = gg[0:1]


if fx != hh:

    print "You got your number baby", hh

else:
    print  "Run this program again"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will give you dates for the next 12 months.
It will exclude days 29-31, so we don't get any imaginary days, like February 31st.

```
import random
days = range(1,29)
months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']
for a in months:
    b = random.choice(days)
    days.remove(b)
    print "Go on Day " + str(b) + " of the month of " + a " "."
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just keep track of the last day number chosen and make sure you don't choose it again. For this year (or any other leap year):

```
import random
months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']
days_in_months = [31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
last_day_number = None
for month,ndays in zip(months,days_in_months):
    while True:
        day_number = random.randint(1,ndays)
        if day_number != last_day_number:
            break
    last_day_number = day_number
    print(day_number, month, '2016')
```

e.g.

```
28 January 2016
22 February 2016
21 March 2016
13 April 2016
21 May 2016
24 June 2016
25 July 2016
9 August 2016
16 September 2016
12 October 2016
5 November 2016
7 December 2016
```

Good luck!

Comment: February, with the exception of leap year has 28 days!

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modified version of [xnx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/293594/xnx)s implementation:

```
import calendar
import random

last_pick = None

for i in range(1, 13):
    month = calendar.month_name[i]
    _, end = calendar.monthrange(2016, i)

    while True:
        day = random.randint(1, end)

        if day != last_pick:
            break

    last_pick = day

    print(day, month, 2016)
```